# How did "Pork Chop" become a term of endearment?

Tags: expressions, hypocorisms

Pork Chop is such an odd term of endearment, any idea what its origin is?

*Update*: For context, I heard the term used in two different contexts.  The first was as a nick-name for my dog who is a large breed female Labrador and at the time was trying to convince someone to share their lunch with her.  The second time I head it used was as a somewhat derogatory reference to someone that was overweight.  In this second example, the nickname wasn't said with malice, more in a jocular manner.

Comment: Where did you hear or read it?  Can you reference any sources?  Sometimes couples invent weird-pet names that only have meaning between them- is this such a case?  As it is, there is not enough to go on to even try to answer.

Comment: Many people are very fond of certain food items, and they find their way into terms of endearment -- _ma petite chou, sweetie, honey, lamb chop, pork chop, crackerjack,_ etc. Affection is affection, metaphorically speaking.

Comment: Let's not forget *pumpkin*.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  Apparently this question is off-topic though I'm not sure why since there are many examples of questions that are worded exactly this same way.  Regardless,  your comments where very helpful and I've voted up those of you that were helpful.  Cheers.